# Can't find for_realloc_lhs symbol in Fortran library build with ifort Intel compiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran, symbols, intel-fortran, abaqus

---

We have built a library with Fortran. But when I try to use it, I always get this error message:

```
libstandardU.so: undefined symbol: for_realloc_lhs
```

We are using abaqus to load functions from our lib:

```
/opt/abaqus/SimulationServices/V6R2018x/linux_a64/code/bin/standard: symbol lookup error: /home/user/libstandardU.so: undefined symbol: for_realloc_lhs
```

For compilation we are using Intel Studio 2018. Ldd shows that it finds it needed libs in the correct intel directory. Is there maybe a flag we need to use to run abaqus or ifort, to enable for_realloc_lhs ? We are mostly C++ programmers and a bit confused. We would realy like to use intel ifort, but are curious: would switch to gfortran help to fix the bug?

The complete output is:

```
Begin Analysis Input File Processor
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:22 AM CEST
Run pre
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:29 AM CEST
End Analysis Input File Processor
Begin Abaqus/Standard Analysis
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:29 AM CEST
Run standard
/cluster/tools/abaqus/SimulationServices/V6R2018x/linux_a64/code/bin/standard: symbol lookup error: /home/carwolff/libstandardU.so: undefined symbol: for_realloc_lhs
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:55 AM CEST
Abaqus Error: Abaqus/Standard Analysis exited with an error - Please see the 
message file for possible error messages if the file exists.
Begin Convert MFS to SFS
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:55 AM CEST
Run SMASimUtility
Tue 02 Oct 2018 08:21:55 AM CEST
End Convert MFS to SFS
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors
```

We start abaqus with this bash script:

```
module load software/abaqus/abaqus_2018
module load intel-studio-2018
input_file=DIC.inp

working_dir=/work/user

### Create ABAQUS environment file for current job, you can set/add your own options (Python syntax)
env_file=custom_v6.env


#########################################################################

cat << EOF > ${env_file}
mp_file_system = (DETECT,DETECT)
EOF

usub_lib_dir=/home/carwolff/
node_list=$(scontrol show hostname ${SLURM_NODELIST} | sort -u)

mp_host_list="["
for host in ${node_list}; do
    mp_host_list="${mp_host_list}['$host', ${SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE}],"
done

mp_host_list=$(echo ${mp_host_list} | sed -e "s/,$/]/")

echo "mp_host_list=${mp_host_list}"  >> ${env_file}


### Set input file and job (file prefix) name here
job_name=${SLURM_JOB_NAME}

### ABAQUS parallel execution
#abaqus job=${job_name} input=${input_file} user=mcd_acustom.f cpus=${SLURM_NTASKS} standard_parallel=all interactive #mp_mode=mpi
#abaqus make -library mcd_acustom.f
abaqus job=${job_name} input=${input_file} cpus=2 standard_parallel=all interactive
```

Edit:

This works, thank you:
If you don't require the Fortran 2003 automatic left hand side reallocation, you may try compiling with -nostandard-realloc-lhs. It was the default in older versions of Intel Fortran. Be careful whether you need it or not though. – Vladimir F Oct 2 at 12:18

Comment: I'd expect `for_realloc_lhs` to be in the library `libifcore.so`.

Comment: If you don't require the Fortran 2003 automatic left hand side reallocation, you may try compiling with `-nostandard-realloc-lhs`. It was the default in older versions of Intel Fortran. Be careful whether you need it or not though.

Comment: I suspect it is an Intel compatibility problem. In the Abaqus 2018 system requirements `Intel® Visual Fortran 16.0 Update 1` is listed as the supported compiler. I'm not familiar with Intel Studio 2018, but it's probably too new and incompatible.

Comment: There is no "bug" here. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used to find shared objects at runtime, and it would seem that a version of libifcore.so from an older compiler version is being found. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/798965 for a similar issue (and resolution).